# Creating a dataframe from raw vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an entry of raw vectors piped in like this below. The real raw vector has more than 50,000 elements. Below is just a snap shot of what few elements look like. As you can see it is hard to decipher where this starts and where this all ends. What I know is this, these are sourced from a dataframe that has 19 columns .

```
     1.1      1.2      1.3      1.4      1.5      1.6      1.7      1.8      1.9     1.10     1.11     1.12     1.13     1.14     1.15     1.16     1.17     1.18     1.19 
      ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       "" 
     2.1      2.2      2.3      2.5      2.6      2.7      2.8      2.9     2.10     2.12     2.13     2.14     2.15     2.16      3.1      3.2      3.3      3.5      3.6 
      ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       "" "9bbb59" "9bbb59"       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       "" 
     3.7      3.8      3.9     3.10     3.12     3.13     3.14     3.15     3.16      4.1      4.2      4.3      4.5      4.6      4.7      4.8      4.9     4.10     4.12 
      ""       ""       ""       ""       "" "9bbb59" "9bbb59"       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       "" 
    4.13     4.14     4.15     4.16      5.1      5.2      5.3      5.5      5.6      5.7      5.8      5.9     5.10     5.11     5.12     5.14     5.15     5.16     5.18 
"9bbb59" "9bbb59"       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""       ""
```

So my goal is to format this raw vector into a dataframe that contains 19 columns like this.

```
Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5  Col6  Col7  Col8  Col9  Col10  Col11  Col12  Col13      Col14    Col15  Col16  Col17  Col18  col19 
NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA      NA        NA        NA     NA     NA     NA      NA 
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     "9bbb59"   "9bbb59"   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     "9bbb59"   "9bbb59"   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA 
NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA     "9bbb59"   "9bbb59"   NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
NA    NA     NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA     NA      NA        NA         NA     NA     NA     NA      NA
```

Please note the numbered rows 1.1, 2.3, 4.3 etc the first number to the left of the dot indicates row number, the second number to the right of the dot indicates column number. 2.13 indicates 2nd row or 2nd observation and column 13.

Any help on accomplishing this is much appreciated.

==========

Example of the above raw vector.

```
dat <- structure(c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"9bbb59", "9bbb59", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "9bbb59", "9bbb59", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "9bbb59", "9bbb59", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), .Names = c("1.1", "1.2", "1.3", 
"1.4", "1.5", "1.6", "1.7", "1.8", "1.9", "1.10", "1.11", "1.12", 
"1.13", "1.14", "1.15", "1.16", "1.17", "1.18", "1.19", "2.1", 
"2.2", "2.3", "2.5", "2.6", "2.7", "2.8", "2.9", "2.10", "2.12", 
"2.13", "2.14", "2.15", "2.16", "3.1", "3.2", "3.3", "3.5", "3.6", 
"3.7", "3.8", "3.9", "3.10", "3.12", "3.13", "3.14", "3.15", 
"3.16", "4.1", "4.2", "4.3", "4.5", "4.6", "4.7", "4.8", "4.9", 
"4.10", "4.12", "4.13", "4.14", "4.15", "4.16", "5.1", "5.2", 
"5.3", "5.5", "5.6", "5.7", "5.8", "5.9", "5.10", "5.11", "5.12", 
"5.14", "5.15", "5.16", "5.18"))
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible example for the given vector. Provide it in a `structure` format

Comment: @YOLO, good point, I have updated the question section based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
vec <- c(1.1, "a", 1.2, "", 2.1, "", 2.2, "b") # in your case, your vector
mat <- matrix(vec,ncol = 2) # in your case, ncol = 19
mat <-mat[seq(2, nrow(mat), by = 2), ]  # we pick only the even columns
mat[mat==""] <- NA # transform "" into NA
mat <- as.data.frame(mat) # now we have a data.frame
```

Best!

Comment: Jonny that didnt work. I have updated my question with a reproducible example of my raw data vector.

Answer (score 0):

Initial thought is create some type of loop.  Depending how dynamic you need it to be, you could rough code something like this.

```
test = data.frame(Var1 = dat[grep("[1-9].1$", names(dat))],
                  Var2 = dat[grep("[1-9].2$", names(dat))],
                  Var13 = c(dat[grep("[1-9].13$", names(dat))], c("","","",""))[1:5])

# You need the concat for columns where there are less than 5 rows.
```